# Efficient INSERT INTO a Table With Clustered Index

Tags: sql-server, performance, insert, clustered-index

I have a SQL statement that inserts rows into a table with a clustered index on the column TRACKING_NUMBER.

E.G.:

```
INSERT INTO TABL_NAME (TRACKING_NUMBER, COLB, COLC) 
SELECT TRACKING_NUMBER, COL_B, COL_C 
FROM STAGING_TABLE
```

My question is - does it help to use an ORDER BY clause in the SELECT statement for the clustered index column, or would any gain acheived be negated by the extra sort required for the ORDER BY clause?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the other answers already indicate SQL Server may or may not explicitly ensure that the rows are sorted in clustered index order prior to the `insert`.

This is dependant upon whether or not the clustered index operator in the plan has the `DMLRequestSort` property set (which in turn depends upon the estimated number of rows that are inserted).

If you find that SQL Server is underestimating this for whatever reason you might benefit from adding an explicit `ORDER BY` to the `SELECT` query to minimize page splits and ensuing fragmentation from the `INSERT` operation

**Example:**

```
use tempdb;

GO

CREATE TABLE T(N INT PRIMARY KEY,Filler char(2000))

CREATE TABLE T2(N INT PRIMARY KEY,Filler char(2000))

GO

DECLARE @T TABLE (U UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),N int)

INSERT INTO @T(N)
SELECT number 
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P' AND number BETWEEN 0 AND 499

/*Estimated row count wrong as inserting from table variable*/
INSERT INTO T(N)
SELECT T1.N*1000 + T2.N
FROM @T T1, @T T2

/*Same operation using explicit sort*/    
INSERT INTO T2(N)
SELECT T1.N*1000 + T2.N
FROM @T T1, @T T2
ORDER BY T1.N*1000 + T2.N


SELECT avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
       fragment_count,
       page_count,
       avg_page_space_used_in_percent,
       record_count
FROM   sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(2, OBJECT_ID('T'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED')
;  


SELECT avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
       fragment_count,
       page_count,
       avg_page_space_used_in_percent,
       record_count
FROM   sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(2, OBJECT_ID('T2'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED')
;
```

Shows that `T` is massively fragmented

```
avg_fragmentation_in_percent fragment_count       page_count           avg_page_space_used_in_percent record_count
---------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------ --------------------
99.3116118225536             92535                92535                67.1668272794663               250000
99.5                         200                  200                  74.2868173956017               92535
0                            1                    1                    32.0978502594514               200
```

But for `T2` fragmentation is minimal

```
avg_fragmentation_in_percent fragment_count       page_count           avg_page_space_used_in_percent record_count
---------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------ --------------------
0.376                        262                  62500                99.456387447492                250000
2.1551724137931              232                  232                  43.2438349394613               62500
0                            1                    1                    37.2374598468001               232
```

Conversely sometimes you might want to force SQL Server to underestimate the row count when you know the data is already pre-sorted and wish to avoid an unnecessary sort. One notable example is when inserting a large number of rows into a table with a `newsequentialid` clustered index key. [In versions of SQL Server prior to Denali SQL Server adds an unnecessary and potentially expensive sort operation](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/668540/unnecessary-sort-operation-for-insert-into-clustered-index-with-newsequentialid-key). This can be avoided by

```
DECLARE @var INT =2147483647

INSERT INTO Foo
SELECT TOP (@var) *
FROM Bar
```

SQL Server will then estimate that 100 rows will be inserted irrespective of the size of `Bar` which is below the threshold at which a sort is added to the plan. However as pointed out in the comments below this does mean that the insert will unfortunately not be able to take advantage of minimal logging.

Comment: [Looks like in 2012 the optimiser would now ignore the explicit sort anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11222043/73226)

Answer (score 13):

It the optimiser decides it would be more efficient to sort the data prior to insert, it will do so somewhere upstream of the insert operator. If you introduce a sort as part of your query, the optimiser should realise that the data is already sorted and omit doing so again.  Note the execution plan chosen may vary from run to run depending on the number of rows inserted from your staging table.

If you can capture execution plans of the process with and without the explicit sort, attach them to your question for comment.

**Edit: 2011-10-28 17:00**

[@Gonsalu's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7350/efficient-insert-into-into-a-table-with-clustered-index/7356#7356) appears to show that a sort operation always occurs, this is not the case. Demo scripts required!

As the scripts were getting quite large, I've moved them to [Gist](https://gist.github.com/1323037). For ease of experimentation, the scripts use SQLCMD mode. Tests run on 2K5SP3, dual core, 8GB.

The insert tests cover three scenarios:

1. Staging data clustered index in same order as target.
2. Staging data clustered index in reverse order.
3. Staging data clustered by col2 which contains a random INT.

First run, inserting 25 rows.

[image: 1st run, 25 rows]

All three execution plans are the same, no sort occurs anywhere in the plan and the clustered index scan is "ordered=false".

Second run, inserting 26 rows.

[image: 2nd run, 26 rows]

This time the plans differ.

- The first shows the clustered index scan as ordered=false. No sort has occurred as the source data is appropriately sorted.
- In the second the clustered index scan as ordered=true, backward. So we don't have a sort operation but the need for the data to be sorted is recognised by the optimiser and it scans in reverse order.
- The third shows a sort operator.

So, there is a tipping point where the optimiser deems a sort to be necessary. As @MartinSmith shows, this appears to be based on the estimated rows to be inserted. On my test rig 25 doesn't require a sort, 26 does (2K5SP3, dual core, 8GB)

The SQLCMD script includes variables that allow the size of the rows in the table to change (altering the page density) and the number of rows in dbo.MyTable before the additional inserts. From my testing, neither has any effect on the tipping point.

If any readers are so inclined, please [run the scripts](https://gist.github.com/1323037) and add your tipping point as a comment. Interested to hear if it varies across test rigs and/or versions.

**Edit: 2011-10-28 20:15**

Repeated tests on same rig but with 2K8R2. This time the tipping point is 251 rows. Again, varying the page density and existing row counts has no effect.

Answer (score 9):

**The `ORDER BY` clause in the `SELECT` statement is redundant.**

It is redundant because the rows that will be inserted, *if they need to be sorted*, are sorted anyway.

Let us create a test case.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CL_Test_ID ON #Test (id);

CREATE TABLE #Sequence (
    number INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #Sequence
SELECT number FROM master..spt_values WHERE name IS NULL;
```

Let's enable the text display of the actual query plans, so we can see what tasks are carried out by the query processor.

```
SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON;
GO
```

Now, let's `INSERT` 2K rows into the table without an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT number
  FROM #Sequence
```

The actual execution plan for this query is the following.

```
INSERT INTO #Test  SELECT number    FROM #Sequence
  |--Clustered Index Insert(OBJECT:([tempdb].[dbo].[#Test]), SET:([tempdb].[dbo].[#Test].[id] = [tempdb].[dbo].[#Sequence].[number]))
       |--Top(ROWCOUNT est 0)
            |--Sort(ORDER BY:([tempdb].[dbo].[#Sequence].[number] ASC))
                 |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([tempdb].[dbo].[#Sequence]))
```

As you can see, there's a Sort operator before the actual INSERT occurs.

Now, let's clear the table, and `INSERT` 2k rows into the table with the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE #Test;
GO

INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT number
  FROM #Sequence
 ORDER BY number
```

The actual execution plan for this query is the following.

```
INSERT INTO #Test  SELECT number    FROM #Sequence   ORDER BY number
  |--Clustered Index Insert(OBJECT:([tempdb].[dbo].[#Test]), SET:([tempdb].[dbo].[#Test].[id] = [tempdb].[dbo].[#Sequence].[number]))
       |--Top(ROWCOUNT est 0)
            |--Sort(ORDER BY:([tempdb].[dbo].[#Sequence].[number] ASC))
                 |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([tempdb].[dbo].[#Sequence]))
```

Note that it's the same execution plan that was used for the `INSERT` statement without the `ORDER BY` clause.

Now, the `Sort` operation is not always required, [as Mark Smith has shown in another answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7350/efficient-insert-into-a-table-with-clustered-index/7353#7353) (if the number of rows to be inserted is low), but the `ORDER BY` clause is still redundant in that case, because even with an explicit `ORDER BY`, no `Sort` operation is generated by the query processor.

You can optimize an `INSERT` statement into a table with a clustered index, by using a minimally-logged `INSERT`, but that's out of scope for this question.

**Updated 2011-11-02:** [As Mark Smith has shown](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7350/efficient-insert-into-a-table-with-clustered-index/7353#7353), `INSERT`s into a table with a clustered index might not always require to be sorted -- the `ORDER BY` clause is also redundant in that case, though.